# Joining tables in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I am joining three tables like below.

```
select t1.empid, t2.sales, t3.date
from table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2 on t1.empid = t2.empid
left outer join table3 t3 on t1.empid = t2.empid 
   and t2.id= t3.id
```

Is this correct, I use `and` condition, thank you.

if i write the proc:  i am joing the table using left outer join

```
select wrh.empid
from Tbl_F_Weekly_Report_Header WRH
left outer join Tbl_Emp_Master_M EM on wrh.EmpId =em.EmpId
LEFT outer join Tbl_F_Emp_Position_M EPS on WRH.PositionCode = EPS.PositionCode 
where EM [Tbl_Emp_Master_M] doesnot contain Positioncode
```

is it correct

Comment: I do not understand your `WHERE` clause.  Can you provide sample data, and expected results?

Comment: ya mr.adma wenger what i have to say is in Tbl_emp_master_m i dont have positioncode it is not where condition.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up.  Your query is correct then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on table3 is incorrect.  You just need:

```
SELECT t1.empid, t2.sales, t3.date
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.empid = t2.empid
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
```

since you have already specified `t1.empid = t2.empid` above in the first `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Your updated query:

```
SELECT wrh.empid
FROM Tbl_F_Weekly_Report_Header AS wrh
LEFT OUTER JOIN Tbl_Emp_Master_M AS em ON wrh.EmpId = em.EmpId     
LEFT OUTER JOIN Tbl_F_Emp_Position_M AS eps ON wrh.PositionCode = eps.PositionCode
```

looks good, just make sure you include `FROM` (was originally missing from your question)

Comment: Please check my another query Mr> Adm Wenger

Comment: @Suryasasidhar I have updated my answer.  Your second query looks good.

Answer (score 0):

yes your sql statement is right. but you might try this:

```
select t1.empid, t2.sales, t3.date
from table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2 on t1.empid = t2.empid
inner join table3 t3 on t2.empid = t3.empid
```

or

```
select t1.empid, t2.sales, t3.date
from table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2 on t1.empid = t2.empid
left outer join table3 t3 on t2.empid = t3.empid
```

Comment: Please check my another query Mr. Rj1516

Answer (score 0):

You just missed slect > select and t3 left outer join. You must use SQL server management studio to test your queries.

```
 select 
 t1.empid,
 t2.sales,
 t3.date 
 from table1 t1 
 left outer join table2 t2 on t1.empid=t2.empid 
 left outer join table3 t3 on t2.id= t3.id
```

Regards

Comment: Please check my another query Mr. BizApps